# Cactoos flatMap analogy

Tags: java, cactoos

Is there [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) analogy in [Cactoos](https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos) library? I need exactly what `flatMap` can, but without streams:

> The flatMap() operation has the effect of applying a one-to-many transformation to the elements of the stream, and then flattening the resulting elements into a new stream.

E.g. if I have some values in list, and each value has children items, and I want to get all items from each value, I can use `flatMap`:

```
List<Value> values = someValues();
List<Item> items = values.stream()
  .flatMap(val -> val.items().stream()) // val.items() returns List<Item>
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How to do the same thing using Cactoos instead of streams API?

Comment: I haven't used Cactoos but I don't see why there would be. Cactoos seeks to replace non-object-oriented methods and structures. A stream is already an object. `flatMap` is an operation on that object. The only thing here that's not in the spirit of Cactoos is `Collectors.toList()` which I suppose would become something like `new ListCollector<>()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Joined](https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/cactoos/iterable/Joined.java), it is the equivalent of flattening an `Iterable`.

For example, you would write:

```
new Joined<>(new Mapped<>(val -> val.items(), someValues()));
```

Comment: Thanks, submitted a PR to show it on README https://github.com/yegor256/cactoos/pull/1058